# ASP.Net: need help with dropdown list bound to a database column

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have created database which has columns

```
 - MemName
 - monthlyAmt
 - CurrentInstAmt
```

I have bound the *Memname* column with a DropDownList box;
onselection of memname value in DropDownList box,  the corresponding values of *currentInstAmt* and *monthlyamt* should be displayed in Textbox.

I am beginer in asp.net

code -

```
DataSet dsMemname = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = strcon;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_Memcollection";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
            adp.Fill(dsMemname);
            ddlmemname.DataTextField = "MemName";
            ddlmemname.DataSource = dsMemname;
            ddlmemname.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Suggestion: Narrow your title so people will know what you are talking about, and give details inside the question

Comment: A little more code would help us help you get from where you are to where you are trying to go.  Do you have a `DropDownList` box bound to a query already?  Do you have an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` Action bound ... if so, what does it look like?

Comment: please check the code i only bound the memname with dropdown

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** 
First, set your dropdownlist's DataValueField, just like the DataTextField: as so:

```
ddlmemname.DataValueField = "MemName";
```

**END EDIT**

Set your dropdownlist's `autopostback="True"` as so:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList1" runat="server" autopostback="true">
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

and then in the code behind for your page, add an event for your drop down as so:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged _
(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selval As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    TextBox1.Text = getMonthlyAmt(selval)
    TextBox2.Text = getCurrentAmt(selval)
End Sub
```

The two get() methods are your own code to look up your relevant values. Also, you may want to optimize them to one call in some manner depending on where you're pulling them from and performance considerations.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means, so I'm not sure what didn't work or what you need expounded upon. Do you mean you didn't get a SelectedValue? This may be because you did not set the DataValueField in your code. It needs to be set, just like DataTextField.